# What is $\mathbf{a}^\bot=(\alpha, \beta)^\bot=(\beta, -\alpha)$ notation?

Tags: notation

I stumbled upon this notation in a book and I cannot find a reference on what this can mean: $\mathbf{a}^\bot=(\alpha, \beta)^\bot=(\beta, -\alpha)$

Here is where I found it:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some context?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, added the original fragment of a book, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, $\vec{a}^{\perp}$ is the vector that is orthonormal to $\vec{a}$ with the same norm. Note that $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}^{\perp} = 0$ and $||\vec{a}^{\perp}|| = ||\vec{a}||$.